# Recurrent CSV import?

Tags: api, csv

We have a client that will give us a .CSV with accounts once a week. I'm wondering how to automate the process of getting this data into SalesForce.

I've been told it can only be done through Open API. Is this true? In such case what is the interface to do it?

Comment: Have you already looked into the integration options and API's exposed by salesforce yourself ? This community expects you show what you've already researched or tried, so that we can help you solve a specific issue. That's the scenario the stackexchange format is most suited for. Other questions tend to be closed fairly quick, so if possible consider updating your question with additional information.

Comment: I'm not a Salesforce customer. One of my clients use it, I called SalesForce and they told me it can be done through API, or a third party solution but I don't have many additional info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our Salesforce org, we created an inbound email service.  This let's us create a special email to be sent to us with an attached file.  We then process the file via Apex and do associated work on the database with it.

The following link should get you started if this is the approach you would like to take:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_inbound_email.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Are you getting any Excel files per Email? If so, how do you handle it redarding the UTF8?

Comment: I really like this option, just a question. The client will create a CSV to their server with a list of contacts once a week. Apart from adding them to the database, could I update the data for leads already in the database? Or add all leads in the CSV to a new Campaign?

Comment: @mast0r only csv files.  I haven't done any excel.

Comment: @LisandroVaccaro sure if u have a way to do it with the info you give.  You write your own custom code for this so you can do pretty much anything you want.

Comment: thanks, that answer my question. I'll award the bounty when I'm allowed to. Just a question: If I had a CSV with users who opened an email, how could I make this info available in Salesforce to sales people (like a list of all these contacts or a log on the lead page)?

Comment: @LisandroVaccaro I'm not sure I understand your question. You can create contacts or lead through code here.

Comment: what I'm asking is what structure is there on Salesforce to save a list of specific leads. So for instance if I import a list of leads who "bought product X", where can I save them so I later can see those specific leads.

Comment: @LisandroVaccaro  Ahhh easy.  They have many such structures for that.  It really depends on what exactly you need.  You can run reports to grab specific criteria.  You can create a new 'View' in the Lead List view that filters by specific criteria.  You can have a VF page do it for you.  Pretty much anything.  Just use a filter that denotes what those specific leads are, so **Leads created on Date X** or **Leads of Type X** or **Leads With X List of fields filled out**.  You aren't exactly saving them at a specific spot, but you can specifically grab them pretty easily.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you are aware of this but you can automate Data Loader. [Here](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/automating-the-apex-data-loader) is a great article to how to do that. If you say that it will always be a .CSV file than this might be a good solution.

Comment: If you have a shared folder they can drop the file to, you can set up a scheduled job on Windows to run Data Loader and reference that file for insert/upsert. However, in this case you'll also have to monitor the error logs for failures.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce does have several data oriented API's, of which the bulk api can work with csv's directly. But you may be better of parsing the csv before sending the data to salesforce. What strategy fits your needs best depends on much more factors than can be answered to your question here.

This is integration, and there are many tools which can help you in setting up this automation, look into ETL tools.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write a program or app which invokes the SOAP API or BULK API. Typically, we can use C# (.NET) or Java to write these programs. Refer to the API documentation for this. 
If you can program, then you can customize the data load as needed.

If you want to avoid coding then you can look into whether the APEX data loader can suit your needs. You can automate the data loading to some extent by running it from the command prompt. 
Read this article which explains the basics.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line

Comment: I've been reading about APEX but it seems to me there still should be some human interaction to use the command line. I'm not sure if it would enable me to completely automate a weekly import for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use Skyvva which allows for scheduled imports and has a free tier https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IsNZEA0

Answer (score 0):

you can upload data like leads, Accounts, contacts etc using Dtaloader.io and the url is https://dataloader.io/ go and click New Task option it's very easy to operate.

Answer (score 0):

If you would not have to enter this data so often, I would use DataLoader. Always it is good to use platform features instead of having to develop something new.

If not, my next question is. Do you need this information just to make it visible, but the customer would not need to modify it, then I would go for Lightning Connect, new Salesforce feature that allow you to read information from an external repository like google doc and show it in Salesforce org in a real time refresh. You would need a Heroku app in order to be able to read google data via OData and also Google API. Once you have the app, just create the External Data Source with the app link and the rest is magic. This [is a nice post](http://www.odata.org/blog/salesforce-external-object-integration-using-lightning-connect-with-odata/) with lot of information.

If you need to show and be able to modify the data, I would go for Email Handler (above response) so your customer send to a Salesforce direction an email with the csv file attach and you can create a simple process in Apex to get the file and attach to a custom object, for instance. 
Once you have it, and via a Batch Apex Process, you can read any csv file in bulk (so you will be sure that no governor limit will be hit) and create your data from the csv file information. Find [here](http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/) also a post that helps how you read a CSV file in Bulk.